# rails respond_to does not stop code from executing further

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, respond-to

I have a couple action inside my cart_controller. I have 2 views inside /carts: `payment.html.erb` and `pay.html.erb`

```
def pay
   success = #do something that returns true or false
   if success
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to '/cart/checkout/review'}
     end
   else
     render_errors
   end
end

def render_errors
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'payment'}
  end
end
```

What i expect is that when

```
success == false
```

it hits render_errors and renders the `payment view` then stop. However what it's doing is: it's rendering  the `payment view` AND THEN it renders the `pay view` as well. So the `payment view` is never shown. What am doing wrong? I'm using Ruby 2.0 on Rails 4.0.

UPDATE:
  I found out that whenever I do `@cart.errors.add(:name, 'error message')` the `pay view` is rendered regardless of any `return` or `respond_to` statements. Any idea?

Comment: is `payment` a partial or a standard view?

Comment: @trh both are standard views.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a long ways ago, but for future Googlers!

Adding a `return` statement at the end of your `respond_to` block should do the trick!

```
def pay
   success = #do something that returns true or false
   if success
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to '/cart/checkout/review'}
     end
   else
     render_errors
   end
end

def render_errors
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'payment'}
  end and return  # here!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't simply call another action in current action, use redirect_to. The respond_to method registers formats like 'html', 'json' to the responder, but does not actually render it. Try this in your controller:

```
def pay
  success = #do something that returns true or false

  redirect_to action: 'render_errors' unless success

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to '/cart/checkout/review'}
  end      
end
```

or this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if success
    format.html { redirect_to '/cart/checkout/review'}
  else
    format.html { redirect_to(:action => 'render_errors') }      
  end
end
```

Comment: i want to keep the context of my current `@cart` instance so i actually don't want to do a `redirect_to` since i'll lose all the instance values.